# python textwrap breaking sentences in wrong places

Tags: python, word-wrap

I'm finding python's textwrap library is breaking sentences in the wrong places.  I'm using:

```
wrp = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=32,break_long_words=False,replace_whitespace=False)
out = '\n'.join(wrp.wrap(txt))
```

Applying this to the following passage*:

```
The Caterpillar and Alice looked at each other for some time in silence:
at last the Caterpillar took the hookah out of its mouth, and addressed
her in a languid, sleepy voice.

'Who are YOU?' said the Caterpillar.

This was not an encouraging opening for a conversation. Alice replied,
rather shyly, 'I--I hardly know, sir, just at present--at least I know
who I WAS when I got up this morning, but I think I must have been
changed several times since then.'
```

The result of the wrap is:

```
The Caterpillar and Alice looked
at each other for some time in
silence:
at last the
Caterpillar took the hookah out
of its mouth, and addressed
her
in a languid, sleepy voice.
'Who are YOU?' said the
Caterpillar.

This was not an
encouraging opening for a
conversation. Alice replied,
rather shyly, 'I--I hardly know,
sir, just at present--at least I
know
who I WAS when I got up
this morning, but I think I must
have been
changed several times
since then.
```

A few of the extra breaks are because the original text is already wrapped.  But still incorrect breaks have been added at e.g. `at last the | Caterpillar`, and the last sentence is a complete mess.  Can anyone advise how to properly wrap this?

- passage sourced with `curl https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/11/pg11.txt | sed -n 960,969p> alice.txt`

Comment: You need to remove previous line feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preserving text format: We replace any return followed or preceded by a letter. That ensure text formatting is kept:

```
re.sub("([,\w])\n(\w)", "\1 \2", sys.stdin.read())
```

> The Caterpillar and Alice looked at each other for some time in silence:
>   at last the Caterpillar took the hookah out of its mouth, and addressed her in a languid, sleepy voice.
>
> 'Who are YOU?' said the Caterpillar.
>
> This was not an encouraging opening for a conversation. Alice replied, rather shyly, 'I--I hardly know, sir, just at present--at least I know who I WAS when I got up this morning, but I think I must have been changed several times since then.'

You can then wrap every parts:

```
text = re.sub("([,\w])\n(\w)", "\1 \2", sys.stdin.read())
for part in text.splitlines():
    print '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(part, width=32))
```

> The Caterpillar and Alice looked
>   at each other for some time in
>   silence:
>   at last the Caterpillar took the
>   hookah out of its mouth, and
>   addressed her in a languid,
>   sleepy voice.
>
> 'Who are YOU?' said the
>   Caterpillar.
>
> This was not an encouraging
>   opening for a conversation.
>   Alice replied, rather shyly, 'I
>   --I hardly know, sir, just at
>   present--at least I know who I
>   WAS when I got up this morning,
>   but I think I must have been
>   changed several times since
>   then.'

Comment: Thanks @cyrbil but unfortunately this deletes all the original line returns, which I need to keep. I like how you've reduced it to a single bash line..

Comment: Exactly as per the original text, but with lines longer than 32 chars to be wrapped.  This means keeping the original line returns, and adding a few more.  My code does that, but it adds the new line returns in the wrong places: e.g. `the\nCaterpillar took` should clearly be `the Caterpillar\ntook`